# I ssh into server A with a common username, when i try to ssh into server B with passwordless I am asked for a password

Tags: ssh

The problem is that when other users login to server A with the same common username they are able to ssh into server B with passwordless login working. This means that it cannot be a permissions problem with the common user on server A.

My passwordless login to server B works from my local host but not after i login to the common user on server A.

Any ideas to what the issue could be would be appreciated. Also let me know any extra info that may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable ssh agent forwarding in order to enable key-based authentication on the second second server. I think a good description is in the [GitHub SSH tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is quite it. I have my own wdroter rsa_id.pub that works for passwordless login on server A and server B. The common user on server A also has its own rsa_id.pub for passwordless login. However once I login to server A as the common user I am still prompted for a password while other users are able to use passwordless login.